# Improving JQuery data

Tags: jquery, optimization

How would you improve this so I wouldn't have to keep repeating?. I will need to create 50 options.

```
var timer = 300;

function showLabels() {
    $('#machine ul#labels li span').animate({'top': '0px'},'slow');
}
function option1() {
    setTimeout(function() { $('#prize-details #prize-text h1').html("Header"); }, timer);
    setTimeout(function() { $('#prize-details #prize-text p').html("Text here"); }, timer);
    $('#machine ul#labels li#what').html('<span>1</span>');
    $('#machine ul#labels li#where').html('<span>2</span>');
    $('#machine ul#labels li#with').html('<span>3</span>');
    $('#machine ul#labels li#in').html('<span>4</span>');
    showLabels();
}
function option2() {
        setTimeout(function() { $('#prize-details #prize-text h1').html("Different header here."); }, timer);
        setTimeout(function() { $('#prize-details #prize-text p').html("Different text here"); }, timer);
        $('#machine ul#labels li#what').html('<span>5</span>');
        $('#machine ul#labels li#where').html('<span>6</span>');
        $('#machine ul#labels li#with').html('<span>7</span>');
        $('#machine ul#labels li#in').html('<span>8</span>');
        showLabels();
    }
```

Comment: It seems both of you functions are similar

Comment: Yes, only difference will be different text in each 50 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both of your functions are similar so you can try with one function like

```
var timer = 300;

function showLabels() {
    $('#machine ul#labels li span').animate({'top': '0px'},'slow');
}

function option(header, para, span1, span2, span3, span4) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
         $('#prize-details #prize-text h1').html(header); 
         $('#prize-details #prize-text p').html(para); 
    }, timer);

    $('#what').html('<span>'+ span1 +'</span>');
    $('#where').html('<span>'+ span2 +'</span>');
    $('#with').html('<span>'+ span3 +'</span>');
    $('#in').html('<span>'+ span4 +'</span>');

    showLabels();
}
```

**According to edit**

If each iteration have different text then call the above function with different parameters like:

```
option('Header', 'Text here', 1, 2, 3, 4);
option('Different Header', 'Different Text here', 5, 6, 7, 8);
```

and so on.

Comment: Sorry, posted updated. Each option will append different text.

Answer (score 0):

is the function `option1` and `option2` the same thing? i cant tell the difference between the 2.

you can make it a bit less readable, but shorter:

```
var timer = 300;

function showLabels() {
    $('#machine ul#labels li span').animate({'top': '0px'},'slow');
}
function option1() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#prize-details #prize-text h1').html("Header"); 
        $('#prize-details #prize-text p').html("Text here");
    }, timer);
    $('#machine ul#labels')
        .find('li#what').html('<span>1</span>').end()
        .find('li#where').html('<span>2</span>').end()
        .find('li#with').html('<span>3</span>').end()
        .find('li#in').html('<span>4</span>');
    showLabels();
}
```

Comment: They will both have different text.

Answer (score 0):

when only the text is different, than use

```
function option(text){
....
setTimeout(function() { $('#prize-details #prize-text p').html(text); }
}
```

It's not much, but i think it would be optimize your code:

```
var temp="#machine ul#labels li"
$(temp+"#what")...
$(temp+"#whre")
```

and so on...

Comment: Each option will append different text. Post Updated.

Comment: than give the text and the header as param

Answer (score 0):

Make a function of it.  You can use an object to carry your data.

```
function option(data) {
    var prizeText = $("#prize-details #prize-text");
    var machineLabels = $("#machine ul#labels");
    setTimeout(function() { $('h1',prizeText ).html("Header"); }, timer);
    setTimeout(function() { $('p',prizeText ).html("Text here"); }, timer);
    for(var n in data)
    {
        $(n).html('<span>' + data[n] + '</span>');
    }
    showLabels();
}

option({
    '#what' : '1'
    '#where' : '2'
    '#in' : '3'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
    new Function(){
        "function option" + i + "() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
           $('#prize-details #prize-text h1').html('"+ myHeaders[i] +"'); 
        }, timer);
        setTimeout(function() { 
           $('#prize-details #prize-text p').html('"+myText[i]+"'); 
        }, timer);
        $('#machine ul#labels li#what').html('<span>1</span>');
        $('#machine ul#labels li#where').html('<span>2</span>');
        $('#machine ul#labels li#with').html('<span>3</span>');
        $('#machine ul#labels li#in').html('<span>4</span>');
        showLabels();
        };option"+i+"();";
    }
}
```

maybe. It is dirty but still a solution :)